# How I can get the value from table in Lua?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I have a table in lua:

```
localhost:3301> box.space.S24.index[1].parts
---
- - type: string
    is_nullable: false
    fieldno: 1
...
```

And I want to get value for key: fieldno. But when I typing this code:

```
localhost:3301> box.space.S24.index[1].parts.fieldno
---
- null
...
```

I got null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the second `-` in front of it in the output; it's an array nested in an array. Try `...parts[1].fieldno`